# How to chain http.request()

Tags: node.js, http

I need to use `require('http')` (I cannot use other libraries), and I am trying to figure out how I would chain multiple `http.request()` together?

In my example below, I am trying to create a household with 4 people, and each person will have a pet associated to them. I have 3 routes that will createFamily, createPerson, and createPet. I also have the method `createHousehold()` that will take the ID's from the response of each route, and pass it down the chain (family -> person -> pet). I am not sure how I would be chaining the response of each route, and passing down the ID.

```
const http = require('http');

createHousehold('Smith', 4); // Creates 'Smith' family with 4 people, and each member has one pet

// Not sure how to chain requests
function createHousehold(surname, numberOfPeople) {
    createFamily(surname)
        .then(familyId => {
            for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
                createPerson(familyId)
                    .then(personId => createPet(personId));
            }
        });
}

function createFamily(surName) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        config: { surName }
    });
    const options = {
        host: 'myProxyHost.com',
        port: '8080',
        path: '/v1/family',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length,
        },
    };
    const request = http.request(options, response => {
        let data = '';
        response.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
        return (response.on('end', () => JSON.parse(data).id));
    });

    request.on('error', error => console.log('ERROR - createFamily(): ', error.message));
    request.write(data);
    request.end();

    return request;
}

function createPerson(familyId) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        config: { familyId }
    });
    const options = {
        host: 'myProxyHost.com',
        port: '8080',
        path: '/v1/person',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length,
        },
    };
    const request = http.request(options, response => {
        let data = '';
        response.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
        return (response.on('end', () => JSON.parse(data).id));
    });

    request.on('error', error => console.log('ERROR - createPerson(): ', error.message));
    request.write(data);
    request.end();

    return request;
}

function createPet(personId) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        config: { personId }
    });
    const options = {
        host: 'myProxyHost.com',
        port: '8080',
        path: '/v1/pet',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length,
        },
    };
    const request = http.request(options, response => {
        let data = '';
        response.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
        return (response.on('end', () => JSON.parse(data).id));
    });

    request.on('error', error => console.log('ERROR - createPet(): ', error.message));
    request.write(data);
    request.end();

    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with a proxy server, you would pipe one request (readable) into another request (writable).

If you are just doing serial requests, I would just wrap them in a promise, or use the async library.

```
function createPet(personId) {

   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

    const data = JSON.stringify({
        config: { personId }
    });

    const options = {
        host: 'myHost.com',
        port: '8080',
        path: '/v1/pet',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length,
        },
    };

    const request = http.request(options, response => {
        let data = '';
        response.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
        response.once('end', () => resolve(data));  // ! resolve promise here
    });

    request.once('error', err => {
       console.log('ERROR - createPet(): ', err.message || err);
       reject(err);  // ! if promise is not already resolved, then we can reject it here
    });

    request.write(data);
    request.end();

  });
}
```

and use it like so:

```
createHousehold(id)
.then(createFamily)
.then(createPerson)
.then(createPet);
```

if you want to do things in parallel, then use Promise.all()..or use the async library.

**For seeding a database, I highly recommend async.autoInject, you will quickly see why:**

https://caolan.github.io/async/v2/docs.html#autoInject

you can use it like so:

```
const seedDatabase = () => {

 return async.autoInject({    // returns a promise

     async createHouseHold(){
        return somePromise();
     },

     async createFamily(createHouseHold){
        return somePromise();
     },

     async createPerson(createFamily){
        return somePromise();
     },

     async createPet(createPerson){   
        return somePromise();
     }

 });

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I need. I should have been more clear in my example but my endpoint exists on a proxy server :)